# Should I use an exception in my "guess a number" program?

Tags: python-3.x, exception

One of the exercises in my assignment is to make program which guesses a number:

```
min=1
max=10
count=1

answer=input("Think of af number between "+str(min)+" and "+str(max)+" and then press enter ")

while answer!="correct":

    if min>max:
        print("\nYou are cheating! Good bye.")
        break

    else:
        guess=(min+max)//2
        answer=input("My no."+str(count)+" guess is "+str(guess)+" - enter 'higher', 'lower' or 'correct': ")

        if answer=="correct":
            print("I guessed it!")

        elif answer=="higher":
            min=guess+1
            count+=1

        elif answer=="lower":
            max=guess-1
            count+=1

        else:
            print("\nCouldn't recognize your input, please try again.")
```

We have just been taught about exceptions, but I'm not really sure if it would make sense to use an exception in this case, maybe instead of the else statement?

Comment: You might find it useful to read [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: if it's fine as it is you don't need to bother with exceptions. You could catch an exception when for examples sake you want an integer off the user but they provide a string, giving you a TypeError which you can then catch to print out something prettier than just a straight up crash.

Comment: Where do you ever assign `answer = "correct"`?